# I get a 400 error when accessing the Admin SDK Api

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace, bad-request

I use `GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/{customerId}/orgunits` to get information about all organizers. I use the service account to authorize requests.

But I get an error 400 bad request.

`{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request", "errors": [ { "message": "Bad Request", "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest" } ] } }`

I tried to do this using other methods where a minimum amount of request data is needed

`GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups`
etc

Result is always the same.

Tell me, maybe I configured something wrong, and what can help me solve my problem?

get success response

Comment: Can I see the rest of your code